# Homepage loads as usual even after adding question mark with random text and number

Tags: wordpress

It is like this

```
https://www.exampledomain.org/?1234
https://www.exampledomain.org/?asdf
https://www.exampledomain.org/?asd123
```

Why is this happening and how do it fix it?

Comment: what did you expect? should it actually load 3 different pages?

Comment: No, I expect it to load pages that are there in the DB, if random stuff has been added then 404 should come up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything passed after the question mark in your URL/Domain is essentially a Query String. Query Strings are basically variables which can be used with PHP for custom logic on your site. This can be done via the superglobal variable $_GET[].

You can read more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php and here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp

This behaviour is expected and functions as it should.